# Linear Superposition Principle vs Energy Conservation during propagation of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, classical-electrodynamics, superposition

Think about focusing an EM beam, and having a divergent beam past the focus. Let r be the distance from the focus to a measurement point. The Linear Superposition Principle implies that the electric field E decreases like r^(-2), while the Law of Energy Conservation implies that E decreases like 1/r. 
I would appreciate a reply fromsomeone who has found this out experimentally.
H. Tomasz Grzybowski, my email: htg@interia.pl

Comment: Why do you think that $E$ and $\vec{E}$ should behave the same way?

Comment: The magnitude of electric fields that are part of radiation fields drop of like $1/r$, to leading order. Where are you getting this "linear superposition principle" from?

Comment: You should explain how the "Linear Superposition Principle" gives you this supposed decrease of the field like $r^{-2}$.

Comment: According to the Linear Superposition Principle the product of the vector E by the surface area which the EM wave crosses is constant during focusing, so we should have E proportional to 1/r^2. –

Answer (score 0):

You need only to apply the law of conservation of energy using Poynting's Theorem for (transverse) EM waves with singular angular frequency $\omega$ and wave vector $k=\omega/c$. The homogeneous wave equation (derived from Maxwell's equations) for the electric field $\vec E$ is $$\Delta \vec E=\frac {1}{c^2} \frac {\partial^2 \vec E}{\partial t^2}$$ This wave equation with spherical symmetry has spherical wave solutions $$ E=\frac {E_0\exp{i(kr-\omega t)}}{r}{}$$ which can be confined entering and exiting the focus within a solid angle $\Omega$. Thus the average power per unit area (intensity) transported by the radially outgoing is given by the average Poynting vector $$ \bar S=c\frac{\epsilon_0 E_0^2} {2r^2}$$ The law of conservation of energy is seen in the spherical surface integral giving the outgoing energy flux of the wave after the focus point at $r=0$ $$\int_\Omega \bar S df=\frac{\Omega}{4\pi}4\pi r^2 c\frac{\epsilon_0 E_0^2} {2r^2}=\Omega c\epsilon_0 E_0^2 =const_r$$ This is obviously independent of $r$ and thus satisfies the conservation of energy according to the Poynting theorem. Before the focus point you get the same incoming energy flux.

The amplitude of the electric field decreases as $1/r$ and thus the energy flux density like $1/r^2$. This is both consistent with the energy conservation which is implicit in the Maxwell equations and thus also the wave equation. I cannot see any direct relation here to the "linear superposition principle".

Comment: Consider a coherent EM wave being focused by a lens whose focal length is much greater than the size of the lens. Consider e.g. 100  rays whose cross-sections are lambda^2 converging at the focal point. Then according to the Principle of Linear Superposition the value of E at the focal point should be about 100*(E-before focusing).

Comment: @H.TomaszGrzybowski - I agree that in a superposition of 100 coherent waves with field strength $E$ you will get a wave with field strength 100 $E$. But how do you derive any $r$-dependence from that?

Comment: According to the Linear Superposition Principle the product of the vector E by the surface area which the EM wave crosses is constant during focusing, so we should have E proportional to 1/r^2.